# Obtener valores mostrados en una lista XamarinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

quiero imprimir los datos que recolecte directamente desde la base de datos hacia un listview, actualmente me imprime datos ingresados de manera manual en la impresora POS printer por red. Este es mi codigo para el botón ya que no puedo capturar los datos con el .ToString ni con el GetValue. Al cargar la pagina inicial me muestra todo los elementos y me gustaria imprimir aquellos mismos elementos.

```
 async void btnenviar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ipAddress = "192.168.3.80";
            int portNumber = 9100;


            var funcion = new VMdetalleventa();
            var parametros = new MdetalleVenta();

            parametros.IdCompra = idcompra;
            parametros.precio_ventaNeto_sindscto = precioventa;
            parametros.Codigo = idproducto;


            var data = funcion.MostrarDetalleVenta(parametros);


            listaDetalleVenta.ItemsSource = data;

            List<string> texto = new List<string>() { listaDetalleVenta.ItemsSource.ToString()};

            var printer = DependencyService.Get<Sasntocielo.VistasModelo.IPrinter>();
            if (printer == null)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "No se implemento en esta plataforma", "OK");
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                printer.Print(ipAddress, portNumber, texto);
              
            }
            catch   (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**

La lista que quiero imprimir esta almacenada

```
   listaDetalleVenta.ItemsSource = data;
```

ya que al cargar la app me muestra de inmediato la lista e intento imprimir en

```
List<string> texto = new List<string>() { listaDetalleVenta.ItemsSource.ToString()};

printer.Print(ipAddress, portNumber, texto);
```

intente con String.Join(",",texto) o texto.string() o simplemente listaDetalleVenta.SelectItem.toString() y siempre termino con un mensaje de
"System.Collection.Generic.List"

Comment: La clase texto debe implementar el metodo ToString() si queres que imprima alguna otra cosa, que no sea el nombre del tipo de objeto ;)

Comment: @gbianchi probe lo mismo que tu me acabas de señalar con anterioridad pensando en eso, pero mi metodo printer.print que tiene el texto es una lista <string> entonces me sale no puedo convertir de string a generic list

Comment: No entendi que trataste de hacer... ssi queres mostrar un ejemplo, podremos ayudarte... si hiciste texto.ToString(), esta mal... lo que tenes que hacer es tu propia lista que sobreescriba el metodo ToString ;)

Comment: Hola no entendi a que te refieres con sobrescribir, actualmente quiero solo los detalles de la lista actual que se muestra. Si hice el toString como dices tú no entiendo como hacerlo de otra forma, estoy bloqueado

Comment: donde lo hiciste, nos lo muestras asi podemos ayudarte a corregir el problema?

Comment: ya edite el POST , como explico allí lo edite en printer. Pero tambien al intentar imprimir solo la lista "texto" me aparece lo mismo. Me percaté que quizas el llamado a la lista "listadetalleventa.itemsource.Tostring()" no es la manera correcta ya que siento que no esta siendo asignada.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta aca:

```
printer.Print(ipAddress, portNumber, texto);
```

Este metodo, pasa la lista (llamada texto) y obviamente, trata de convertir a texto "texto", como si hicieras:

```
texto.ToString();
```

Pero como texto es una lista, que hereda de object, entonces usa la definicion standard de [`ToString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-6.0), que basicamente, le dice, imprimi de que tipo soy.

Como te decia, tenes que sobreescribir ese metodo para que al llamarlo, no imprima lo standard, si no lo que vos queres que imprima, en esta caso, supongo el contenido de la lista.

Para eso, nada mejor que [esta respuesta en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1340145/73749) que te explica como sobreescribir ese metodo, creando una subclase de lista.